# Need help working with an associate array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a function to loop through an array and grab the values that has an array index of "weekday_time_start" and "weekday_time_end". I have wrote a function that should do that but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Can anyone please help me figure this on out. This is what have so far

```
Value of the the $cat_time_array

array(
['weekday_time_start'] =>
'07:30 AM'
['weekday_time_end'] =>
'10:45 PM'
['weekend_time_start'] =>
['weekend_time_end'] =>
)


 public  function SetWeekdayCategoryVisibility($cat_time_array){


    foreach ($cat_time_array as $key=>$value){


        if($key  == "weekday_time_start" ){
            $weekday_start = $value;
        }

        if($key == "weekday_time_end"){
            $weekday_end = $value;
        }


        $this->CompareTimes($weekday_start,$weekday_end);
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Also when you use associative arrays, you can't use same key twice. (this is for your array output)

Comment: why not just  `$this->CompareTimes($cat_time_array['weekday_time_start'],$cat_time_array['weekday_time_end']);`

Comment: I think OP has wrong expectation from associative arrays

Comment: @Dagon Thank you for your reply! I actually didn't think of doing that. I am so used using foreach loops when working with array's thatit has become the first thing i think about. I've did what you said and it worked. It was such a simple solution, I can't believe I missed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should move the call to `CompareTimes` to outside the loop.

But you don't need the loop at all, and using it rather defeats the purpose of having an associative array in the first place:

```
$this->CompareTimes($cat_time_array["weekday_time_start"], 
                    $cat_time_array["weekday_time_end"]);
```

Comment: @Mark Reed. Thanks a lot for the reply. Dagon just gave me the same solution. I can't believe I missed such as simple solution. I have foreach stuck in my head when working with array's.

Comment: I technically posted my answer a bit less than a minute before Dagon posted his comment, but like he said, great minds - and also ours. :)  Please accept my answer if it was useful to you.